# I can't connect ssh "write: Connection reset by peer" ubuntu

Tags: bash, ssh, shell

I try to connect using ssh but the following error is happening randomly

```
ssh martial@192.168.xxx.xxx -vvvv
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "192.168.xxx.xxx" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.xxx.xxx [192.168.xx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/adminmartial/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/adminmartial/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/adminmartial/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/adminmartial/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/adminmartial/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/adminmartial/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/adminmartial/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/adminmartial/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
write: Connection reset by peer
```

Do you know what the error could be?

Comment: Is this the complete trace? It is possible that the only authentication method available is using public keys

Comment: This is the complete trace and i'm already using a publickey.

Comment: Is ~/.ssh/id_rsa really there? Check permissions

Comment: Your TCP connection is being dropped by the server (or by something like a firewall) before any kind of data exchange or authentication takes place. You should check on the server for any log messages by the ssh server software which might indicate why it's dropping the connection.

Comment: @sudo When I try to connect a 2nd time, the connection successfully completes. This problem happens  frequently

Comment: @kenster In /var/log/auth.log i have **sshd[6171]: Received signal 15; terminating.** and i don't have a firewall at the moment my iptables rules are accept for all.